# How to pass object through dispatch in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

getting value form the user to find odd or even using redux. i am creating a reducer function and passing the action inside reducer function and store this function

```
const Reduceraction = (state,action) => {
        console.log('action', action)
        switch (action.number%2) {
            case  0:
                window.alert('it is a odd number')
                break
            case 1:
                window.alert('it is a odd number')
                break
            default:
                window.alert('wrong')
                break;
        }

    }

    let store = createStore(Reduceraction);

    return (
        <div>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <Demo3  />
            </Provider>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here i get value from user and send this value through dispatch to find odd or even

```
function Demo3() {
    const selector = useSelector(state => state)    
     const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [state, setstate] = useState();
    return (
        <div>
                {selector}
                <input onChange={(e)=>setstate(e.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={()=> dispatch({number : state})} >check</button>
                
        </div>
    )
}
```

but i got error

```
Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. Redux Actions are plain JavaScript objects that have a **type** field. Your reducer function should handle each type of action. Like this:

```js
const Reduceraction = (state = { message: '', number: -1 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHECK_NUMBER':
      if (action.number % 2 === 0) {
        return { message: 'it is a even number', number: action.number };
      }
      return { message: 'it is a odd number', number: action.number };
    default:
      break;
  }
};

// In your component
const number = useSelector(state => state.number);
const message = useSelector(state => state.message);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// somewhere
dispatch({type: 'CHECK_NUMBER', number: 2});

// somewhere
window.alert(message);
```

Besides, you can't use `window.alert()` inside the reducer function, redux reducer functions should be pure. You should use `window.alert()` inside the component.

I suggest you read the documentation of redux.